# HTTP 400 bad request when url contains non-asciii characters

Tags: javascript, java, spring, internet-explorer

This is my js file which passes the query string parameters to controller.

```
function viewSelectedTravelerDetails(taNumber,country,city)
{
    // clearMessageBar();       
    if(taNumber != "")
    {
        var url = "travelerdetailview.htm?requestAction=viewTravelerDetails&taNumber="+taNumber+'&country='+country+'&city='+city;
        //var url = "travelerdetailview.htm?requestAction=viewTravelerDetails&taNumber="+taNumber;
        var windowName = "traveler_detail";
        var retValue = openNewWindow(url,windowName,"width=1024px,height=768px,center=1, status=0, titlebar=0, margin=0 auto,scrollbars=yes");
    }

}
```

This is the controller method which handles the above requested url and returns view in case of other records.

```
private ModelAndView handleTravelerDetailView(
      HttpServletRequest  request
    , HttpServletResponse response
    , Object              command
    , BindException       errors
) throws Exception {

    String taNumber = request.getParameter("taNumber");
    String country  = request.getParameter("country");
    String city     = request.getParameter("city");

    logIt.info( "Traveler city(ISO_8859_1):" + city );

    byte[] bytes = city.getBytes( StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 );

    city = new String( bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );

    logIt.info( "Traveler city(UTF-8):" + city );

    TravelerCO travelerViewData = migrateDataService.retrieveTravelerFullData( taNumber, country, city );

    logIt.info( "Traveler city(retrieveTravelerFullData):" + travelerViewData.getTravelerCity() );

    return new ModelAndView( getSuccessView(), getCommandName(), travelerViewData );
}
```

It fails to process the request if url contains non-ascii characters like

> travelerdetailview.htm?requestAction=viewTravelerDetails&taNumber=TA17/1246&country=&city=**Malé**

Why do I get 400 bad request error? Please note the UTF-8 characters in url.

Comment: Please include the error message in your question, then indent your code